# Is it legal to pass a pointer to a function expecting an array?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the code:

```
double func(double a[3])
{
    /* do something with a and return */
}

int main(void)
{
    std::vector<double> test(LARGE_NUM_DIVISIBLE_BY_3);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < LARGE_NUM_DIVISIBLE_BY_3 / 3; ++i)
    {
        test[3 * i] = /* some random double */;
        test[3 * i + 1] = /* some random double */;
        test[3 * i + 2] = /* some random double */;

        double val = func(&test[3 * i]);
    }
}
```

Is this defined behavior in C++11? I.e., can I pass a pointer (`&test[3 * i]`) to a function that expects an array (`double func(double a[3])`)? I know if I were to go the other way (i.e., pass an array to a function that expects a pointer), the array would decay to a pointer - does the reverse also work?

Comment: No, `a` will not be returned, just used to calculate the return value

Comment: You are saying array and showing vector. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I disagree with the duplicate tag - I want to know if the reverse situation of that question is legal, as I have already made explicit.

Comment: And the dupe explains it is.  `void by_value(const T* array)   // const T array[] means the same`

Comment: @NathanOliver: It actually explicitly states "when passing in an array" (whereas I want to pass in a pointer) right before that code block, but I'll believe you that it works the other way as well. That was my intuition, as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really pass arrays like that. Any argument declaration like `double a[]` (with or without a size) is translated by the compiler as a pointer, `double* a`.

And arrays naturally *decays* to pointers to their first element. So if you have an *actual* array (and not a vector) like

```
double test[SOME_SIZE];
```

then passing it when a pointer is expected (like `test`) will pass a pointer to its first element (`&test[0]`).

For vectors that's not possible though, and you have to explicitly pass a pointer like you already do.